# How to change SSL certificate from localhost to something else in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis-express

I changed my Visual Studio project url from https://localhost:port_number to https://ip_address:port_number. I did create a self-signed certificate where DNS name is actual IP address. How do I make my project to use my new self-signed certificate instead of self sighed certificate with DNS name locahost.

Comment: "where DNS name is actual IP" That does not really make sense. The whole purpose of DNS is to map a humanly readable strings (like stackoverflow.com) to machine readable IP adresses. And this mapping is intentionally not static. You can (and should never try to) asume anything about the IP adress you will be reachable under. Just keep it on the DNS Name.

Comment: This is for a development environment not production. OK let's say I create self-signed certificate with actual DNS name like 'test'. How to I tie my project in Visual Studio with this certificate ?

Comment: Either you use `netsh` command to manipulate it, or use a tool like Jexus Manager, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/self-signed.html

Comment: Surprised this is not a more commonly asked question. Running into a need for this myself connecting to an HTTPS web api running in debug mode on one machine while trying to connect to it from an iPhone app in a Simulator on a Mac on the same LAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Here is the link to the blog where, basically, spells out how it is done. https://wp.sjkp.dk/custom-domains-and-ssl-bindings-with-iis-express/